# Flutter show/hide options bar over pdf viewer

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter

I'm trying to keep the track on the page a user is reading from a pdf so first I tried to control the scroll for the file which does not make much sense as a pdf is displayed as it is, so if I split the pdf pages into different files I can keep the track but to allow the user change the page I'd like to add some controls like next page and previous page. First I tried to add a Floating Action Button which should be hidden and displayed when the user tap the screen so I did this:

I'm using flutter_full_pdf_viewer plugin.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_full_pdf_viewer/full_pdf_viewer_scaffold.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Little Readers',
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String pathPDF = "";
  double iconSize = 80;
  MaterialColor iconColor = Colors.blue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    createFileOfPdfUrl().then((file) {
      setState(() {
        pathPDF = file.path;
        print(pathPDF);
      });
    });
  }

  Future<File> createFileOfPdfUrl() async {
    final url = "http://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf";
    final filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    var response = await request.close();
    var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
    String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    File file = new File('$dir/$filename');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    return file;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('My App'),
      ),
      body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    iconSize: iconSize,
                    color: iconColor,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.book),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => PDFScreen(pathPDF)),
                        ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}

class PDFScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  String pathPDF = "";
  PDFScreen(this.pathPDF);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          PDFViewerScaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("My Book"),
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                  onPressed: () => {},
                )
              ],
            ),
            path: pathPDF,
          ),
          Positioned(
            child: new FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
              backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade800,
              onPressed: () => {},
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the problem is FAB is displayed at the AppBar no matter if I set the top, bottom, left or right properties, it actually moves depending on the position I set but only through the AppBar.

[image]

As an alternative and actually I think it would be a more elegant solution I'd like to add an options bar just as the images gallery at android does when you tap on the image.

[image]

of course I want to get it over the pdf viewer, but I'm having issues to find a component or a way to do it. So I'm looking for some direction on this...

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I actually just recently had to do something like this myself. I wrapped my floating action button with an Align widget like this.

```
floatingActionButton: Align(
      child: Container(
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          heroTag: 'scaffoldBtn'+_scafKey.hashCode.toString(),
          onPressed: () {
            _scafKey.currentState.openDrawer();
          },
          backgroundColor: Utils.hexToColor('#07467A'),
          tooltip: 'Menu',
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 13.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.menu),
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
              right: Radius.circular(20.0),
            ),
            side:
                BorderSide(color: Utils.hexToColor('#979797'), width: 2.0),
          ),
        ),
        width: 65.0,
        height: 55.0,
      ),
      alignment: Alignment(-0.99, 0.9),
    ),
```

Here's a link to the Align widget for more details. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html

Hope this helps!